# Can't make jQ UI tabs work w/ cookie after jQ/UI upgrade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cookies, tabs

I have this piece of code, that uses cookies to make jquery tabs selection persist trough refresh

The problem is that it only works with jQuery UI 1.7.2 and  jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.1

If i update to jQuery UI - v1.10.0 and jQuery JavaScript Library v1.9.0, it doesn't persist anymore (no errors, just not persisting tab selection across page loads)

Anyone know why ?

Here is the code

```
$( function(){
  var cookieName = 'stickyTab';
  $( '#tabs' ).tabs( {
     selected: ( $.cookies.get( cookieName ) || 0 ),
     select: function( e, ui ){
       $.cookies.set( cookieName, ui.index );
     }
  } );
} );
```

in my html i have

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookies.js"></script>
```

cookie is provided by http://code.google.com/p/cookies/

Comment: I am the author of that cookie plugin, and that tabs code. I am woefully behind on keeping the plugin up to date, but the way you are using it is not using any jQuery functionality and should work fine. I believe the tabs API may have changed. I will look into that line of reasoning and post an answer if I find one.

Comment: Update to last comment--the tabs API has changed. I am posting an answer.

Comment: The question header is misleading. It should clarify that you mean JQuery UI, and not [jQ UI](https://github.com/01org/appframework/tree/master/ui)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cookie code is fine, but the jQuery UI Tabs API has changed with your upgrade.

1. `selected` is no longer a valid option--it has been renamed to `active`.
2. `select` is no longer a valid event--it has been changed to `activate`.
3. The `index` property of the `ui` param which gets passed into `activate` has been removed, leaving more work to be done to figure out which tab just went active.

Here is a live demo of the new API in use: http://jaaulde.com/test_bed/stickytabNewAPI/

And here is the specific JS:

```
    $(function () {
        var cookieName = 'stickyTabNewAPI',
            $tabs = $('#tabs'),
            $lis = $tabs.find('ul').eq(0).find('li');

        $tabs.tabs({
            active: ($.cookies.get(cookieName) || 0),
            activate: function (e, ui) {
                $.cookies.set(cookieName, $lis.index(ui.newTab));
            }
        });
    });
```

I can understand the name change from select to activate, etc. I do not, however, understand why they dropped the `index` property of the `ui` param. It makes for more work...

Comment: @punked, I am working on a new version of my sticky accordion. Could you please post a new question using the original here, modified to be specific to the new accordion API, and send me a link? Thanks!

Comment: here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746108/cant-make-jq-ui-accordion-work-w-cookie-after-jq-ui-upgrade